# how to get percentage for the each year in R when grouped?

Tags: r, dataframe, calculation

[image: the dataFrame I am using]

this is the DataFrame I am working on.

I want the data to show the result in percentages corresponding to that year only

I tried grouping them as

```
years <- trips_data %>% 
  select(year, member_casual, ride_length_mins) %>%
  group_by(year, member_casual) %>% 
  summarise(count_percentage = n()/nrow(trips_data ), sum(ride_length_mins)) %>% 
  mutate(percentage_of_rides = scales::percent(percentage_of_rides))
```

but the result shows each year % as as a part of all 4 years like this
[image: unwanted result]

the desired output is like

[image: desired output]

I cannot think of a way to achieve this without making individual variables for each year by filtering. and hard coding

any advice or help is much appreciated, thank you

Here is the  Reproducible sample

```
structure(list(year = c("2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2017", "2017", "2017", 
"2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", 
"2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
"2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018"), member_casual = c("casual", 
"casual", "casual", "casual", "casual", "casual", "member", "member", 
"member", "member", "member", "member", "member", "member", "member", 
"member", "member", "member", "casual", "casual", "casual", "casual", 
"casual", "casual", "casual", "casual", "casual", "casual", "casual", 
"member", "member", "member", "member", "member", "casual", "casual", 
"casual", "casual", "casual", "member", "member", "member", "member"
), ride_length_mins = c(28, 21, 2, 27, 27, 22, 14, 11, 4, 18, 
4, 10, 16, 11, 13, 8, 10, 21, 15, 22, 23, 15, 16, 16, 16, 25, 
16, 12, 23, 14, 4, 6, 5, 7, 24.6833333333333, 7736.13333333333, 
22.6833333333333, 24.6833333333333, 7736.13333333333, 22.6833333333333, 
52.2166666666667, 52.6333333333333, 49.3)), row.names = c(NA, 
-43L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the `nrow(trip_data)`, we may need to get the row grouped by 'member_casual

```
library(dplyr)
 trips_data %>% 
  add_count(year, member_casual) %>% 
  add_count(year, name = 'year_n') %>%
  group_by(year, member_casual) %>%
  summarise(count_percentage = first(n)/first(year_n),
    Sum = sum(ride_length_mins), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  mutate(count_percentage = scales::percent(count_percentage))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  year  member_casual count_percentage    Sum
  <chr> <chr>         <chr>             <dbl>
1 2016  casual        33.3%              127 
2 2016  member        66.7%              140 
3 2017  casual        68.8%              199 
4 2017  member        31.2%               36 
5 2018  casual        100.0%           15721.
```

---

If we want the Sum to be based on percentage

```
trips_data %>% 
  add_count(year, member_casual) %>% 
  add_count(year, name = 'year_n') %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(Sum = sum(ride_length_mins)) %>%
  group_by( member_casual, Sum, .add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(count_percentage = first(n)/first(year_n), 
     .groups = 'drop') %>% 
  mutate(Sum = Sum * count_percentage,
    count_percentage = scales::percent(count_percentage))%>%   
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(Sum = Sum/sum(Sum)) %>%
  ungroup
# A tibble: 5 × 4
  year  member_casual   Sum count_percentage
  <chr> <chr>         <dbl> <chr>           
1 2016  casual        0.333 33.3%           
2 2016  member        0.667 66.7%           
3 2017  casual        0.688 68.8%           
4 2017  member        0.312 31.2%           
5 2018  casual        1     100.0%
```

Comment: hello, thanks for advice, I tried using this method but the problem is still the same, the casual row of 2016 and members row of 2016 still don't add up as 100%,  casual 2016 is 26.005% where as member of 2016 is 22.863%

Comment: i have updated a small sample of the data frame in post

Comment: @ElJoven Does the update works for you

Comment: Yha! ,  i used the chunk you gave it does work . thank you very much for your time and efforts.

Comment: hello, i finally undestood the logic behind it . can you guide me how can I also get the same result for minutes like the sum column

Comment: @ElJoven what would be the output in `Sum` column

Comment: @ElJoven Do you want `trips_data %>% 
  add_count(year, member_casual) %>% 
  add_count(year, name = 'year_n') %>% group_by(year) %>% mutate(Sum = sum(ride_length_mins)) %>%
  group_by( member_casual, Sum, .add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise(count_percentage = first(n)/first(year_n), .groups = 'drop') %>% mutate(Sum = Sum * count_percentage, count_percentage = scales::percent(count_percentage))`

Comment: its logic is summing up both row of each year casual and member and devinding them with single row to get the %

Comment: @ElJoven try the update in my post

Comment: nah it's not working, but never mind,  I will try to figure it out myself , once again thanks

Comment: yep tried couldn't get it, in the output given by you in the "Sum" column the values are "89' and "178" in their places I want 0.33% (89/(89+178)) and 0.64% ((178/(89+178))

Comment: @ElJoven I get `178/(89 + 178)
[1] 0.6666667` (updated)

Comment: damn your genius man !!